# file write with file name's including frame number as postfix in c

Tags: c, file-handling

I need to do file write with file name as : fine_%d.y.

My input: input.y has 400 frames.

```
input -> Gaussian Algorithm -> file_%d.y
```

Can any one suggest me how can I write the logic in "C".

I am running test case running on a small operation of Gaussian filter on given frame and storing result in output frame.

I want to dump each output frame.

**NOTE: Wants to write in C only.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    FILE* f0_in = fopen("input_400FRames.y", "r");
    if (NULL == f0_in) {
        printf("REF: Error in opening input file \n");
        return 0;
    }

    int width = 1280;
    int height = 720;

    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * width * height);
    if (input == NULL) {
        exit (1);
    }

    int inputsize = sizeof(unsigned char) * width * height;
    uint32_t frame_number = 0, frame_size = width * height;

    /* frame loop */
    while(!feof(f0_in)) {

        size_t size =  fread(input, 1, inputsize, f0_in);
        if (size == 0) {
            printf ("REF: Error in reading luma content: %zu\n", size);
            break;
        }

        if(size == frame_size) {

            //How I can make sure file name varies with every frame number
            //file_%d.y =  file_frame_number.y
            //Error: fopen(file_%d.y, .. -> Just to put this to show support my question
            FILE* f_out = fopen(file_%d.y, "w");
            if (NULL == f0_in) {
                printf("REF: Error in opening output file\n");
                return 0;
            }

            //Gaussian filer execution over a complete frame

            fwrite(input, sizeof(unsigned char) * width * height, 1, f_out);

            fclose(f_out);


        }
        frame_number++;
    }



    fclose(f0_in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't put the format string directly into the `fopen` call, but you can do it in two steps: Create a `char` buffer that is large enough, `sprintf`or `snprintf` to it, then pass it to `fopen` as filename.

Comment: Thank you your suggestion solve my problem.

Comment: @MOehm, One question, Can I put name as `input_name_%d.y` ..here I do have different input streams .example street.y, flower.y, crowd.y .. the name will be any thing.I need to create output as flower_0.y also street_0.y etc .. Is that possible using snprint ?

Comment: There is a whole family of `...printf` functions. They all take the same printing formats in their strings. So if `printf("%s.%d", type, number)` works (which it should if `type` is a string and `number` is an int), then `char buf[80]; snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s.%d", type, number)` works, too.